# React Style props not reflect in IE

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am using react to build a web application.
I have a simple div tag want to use flexbox style and set the style props like below

```
<div style={styles.container}>...</div>
```

and style define like below

```
const styles = {
container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
}}
```

it works fine in chrome(v53) and rendered like below html

```
<div data-reactroot="" 
style="flex: 1 1 0%; justify-content: center; align-items: center; 
background-color: rgb(245, 252, 255); display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
....
</div>
```

while visited in ie(v11.633) several style are not rendered in the html,which cause the content in the div not display properly

```
<div style="display: flex; background-color: rgb(245, 252, 255);" data-reactroot="">
...
</div>
```

my question is whether react will apply the style according to the browser? and how to apply flexbox style correctly across browsers 

----------update--------
I tried in EDGE and Firefox all will render the style correctly,

Comment: [This](https://github.com/storybooks/react-storybook/issues/213) might be relevant as well.

Comment: I think flex is not an option ie 10 knows, but your meta tag answer should be fine ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally I noticed that the render engine selected by IE is v10 and it will work fine with render engine v11.so I tried to change the render engine in IE,added below in the header of html and it is rendered correctly(in IE11 not tried in other version)

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Don't know why IE engine 10 does not render the style correct, but finally this solve my problem. Thanks all.